# How can I use a solvent gradient in column chromatography?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chromatography

I am working to use the column, there are a lot of videos which explain it, but I don't understand this statement in the procedure.

> The residue was finally purified by column chromatography using 100 % dichloromethane to 1:1 ethyl acetate/petroleum ether to 100 % ethyl acetate as solvent gradient

Could you please explain?

Comment: Please give a background to this question. What residue, why are you doing this, what is your educational background, what kind of column, etc. And btw. I recommend economising on the exclamations marks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a gradient in column chromatography means that the nature and composition of the solvent(s) used as eluent is changed during the process.

This can allow an easy and overall faster separation of compounds, either emphasising little difference in retention coefficients or taking advantage of the fact that some compounds are almost totally retained while others are eluted faster.

An extreme example is a mixture of a very polar compound and an unpolar one. In this case the separation will be easy anyway, but recovering both compounds would require an extremely long running time if the polarity of the eluent isn't varied on the go.

In your case the "column started" with dichloromethane until the elution of one or more compounds.
Then the eluent was switched to a polar one with a smooth transition ensured by 1:1 ethyl acetate/petroleum ether.

Note that besides retention considerations the switching must be performed gradually and not abruptly. Very rapid changes in polarity, meaning different interaction between the changing eluent and the stationary phase, can ruin the packing of the column and, in some cases, *ignite the eluent* if the process is exothermic enough.

Gradient is a common procedure in other chromatographic techniques as well, and can involve T as a parameter. The underlying principle remain the same.

See for instance http://www.chromedia.org/chromedia?waxtrapp=mxrorDsHqnOxmOlIEcCzBiDpC&subNav=curorDsHqnOxmOlIEcCzBiDpCbB